# Cpanel alternative with auto installation

Tags: web-hosting, automation, automated-install

I'm looking for a free open source cPanel alternative which also includes auto installation software or can be easily configured to integrate an auto installation application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Totally off topic, but as a (very small time) hosted services employee, I think auto-install web applications are the tool of the devil.  The ones I have dealt with have absolutely no provision for dealing with updates to the applications in question -- they can install this version, now, and that's it.

When an update happens (and it will) there's no ability to roll out this update to those users who have already click-and-installed.  There's precious-little ability to even track who's installed what!

This might be fine, if the click-and-installer was someone who understood the transient nature of web applications -- especially the free or open-source applications favored by many of these click-and-install kits -- but unfortunately they end up appealing to a user community which expects to install it once and run it forever.

This ends up being a problem for the hosting provider, since these unmaintained applications end up attracting automatic compromise scripts, with the result that everyone on the shared service suffers from poor service.

I turn off the click-and-install applications in the hosting packages we use because I got tired of spam-spewing perl scripts getting dropped on my servers via poorly maintained applications.

We advise all prospective customers that they need to pay attention to their web presence, and if they don't feel comfortable or have the time to do it themselves, they should find a professional to assist them.  We can even assist them in finding such a professional (since we don't do that part of the business ourselves).

Totally off-topic.

But don't do it.